# При установке соединения ошибка 443

Tags: сервер, gitlab

При попытке установить соединение между сервисом аналитики и `GitLab` получаю сообщение:

`'Unable to connect to Gitlab API with the provided credentials - ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'http\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //161.97.67.203//api/v4/groups?page=1&per_page=50 (Caused by NewConnectionError(\'<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff80bec100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known\'))"))')`

Почему возникает эта ошибка и как ее устранить?

Comment: попробуйте вот тут посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication

Comment: У вас между "http" и "//" в урле пробел.